# connection to mariadb on virtual machine via ssh failed in php script

Tags: php, mysqli, mariadb

I currently have a virtual machine setup to be connected to via ssh and contains a mariadb database. I am trying to run a php script to connect to it and query the database, but I cannot get past the connection without it saying

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused

My php code that deals with this connection looks like the following:

```
set_include_path(':/Users/self/pear/share/pear' . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib/');
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('IP_Address');
    if (!$ssh->login('user', 'password')) {
        exit('Login Failed');
    }
$mysqli = new mysqli("IP_Address", "root", "password", "test_db");
    $connect_errno = array();
    $connect_error = array();
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        $connect_errno[] = ($mysqli->errno);
        $connect_error[] = ($mysqli->error);
    }
```

I have checked multiple times and the password/username/ip address above are all correct so it can't be that (Also I believe it would say 'Access Denied' rather than 'Connection Refused')